# Attesters consider attestations from other attesters at the same slot for getting head?

Tags: chain-reorganization, attestations, fork-choice-rule

I was looking into
ex-post reorg presentations and documents by Caspar Schwarz.

https://vimeo.com/637529564

I got something awkward.
In ex-post reorg explanation,
it seems like attesters doesn't consider attestations from the current slot for deciding current head block.

So Caspar says that
when proposer boost is 0,
for ex-post reorg,
attackers need to have 2/3 votes in n+1 slot and n+2 slot for pulling out n+1 block.

In slot n+1,
1/3 honest attesters will vote for n+1 block, and
2/3 attackers will vote for n block.

The problem is in slot n+2.
In slot n+2,
Caspar says attackers need 2/3 of the committee
because 1/3 honest attesters will vote for n+1 block
(because n+1 block has 1/3 votes already, but n+2 block has nothing).

However, what if attackers broadcast their attestation for n+2 slot right after they broadcast the n+2 block?

Then honest attesters will include those attestations for head decision.
Then it means attackers just need 1/3 of the committee for fighting with the
1/3 votes of honest attesters in n+1 slot.

Please let me know if this is wrong.